# Dom Manipulation (AppendChild) fails in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, jest-dom

I need some  help in below test case : appenChild failing in Jest

```
updatePopupContent(data) {
    const sectionFragment = new DocumentFragment();
    //create section return HTML element as per data passed
    data.costSection && sectionFragment.appendChild(this.createSection(data.costSection));// test fails here
    this.dom.content.appendChild(sectionFragment);
}

describe('test functionality', () => {
            const data = {
                costSection: {
                    price: "10 USD"
                }
            }
            it("should create subsections ", () => {
                context.createSection = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
                    const section = document.createElement("div");
                    section.innerHTML = "Test Section";
                    return section;
                })
                context.updatePopupContent(data); // throwing error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'adoptNode' of undefined
                expect(context.createSection).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            })
```

Actually this is an issue with JSDOM : https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2274
What changes I need to make in test to get the error resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, [commit f9dc6271a8ed557d7557967b87b51bed42a4d932](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/commit/f9dc6271a8ed557d7557967b87b51bed42a4d932) provides a fix for issue you've faced. And seems to be included into JSDom [16.0.0 release](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases/tag/16.0.0).

All you need to do is to update your `jest`, so its `jest-environment-jsdom` points at least to `jsdom 16.0.0`. Based on history for [its `package.json`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/package.json) you need at least `26.0.1`